# Background color in <Body> isn't filling up the whole screen

Tags: html, css, height

I want to setup a background color in my front page, so I added the following lines in the body section:

```
    <head>
<title>Speed_Test_Teleport</title>
</head>
<body style="height:100% ;margin:0 ;padding:0 ;background-color:#C6E2FF;">
<img src="GE_Logo3.png" style="width=350px; height:80px;">
<h1>SpeedTest to:</h1>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 24vh; text-align: center ; color:#8B0000 ; display:inline-block;">
<div style="width: 100%; height: 15px; text-align: center; font-family: palatino ;display: inline-block;"><font size="+3"><b>Teleport,Country </b></font>
```

However, the background color is only covering 60% of the screen; the bottom is filled up with white color:

[image: Snapshot of results]

After checking other posts, it seems like height, margin and padding are set to the right values, but as you see, the background color is just partially filling the screen.

Any idea on what I'm missing?

If need further info, you can see the whole code at index.html:

https://github.com/olg33/ST/blob/master/index.html

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable. Provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) if you're asking about HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Put the height in body 100vh instead of 100%.

```
<body style="height:100vh;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#C6E2FF;">
```

Comment: Thanks Soni! Your suggestion fixed the problem.